# Need To Add A Class To Last List Item Element In Custom Wordpress Loop Function Prefer jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loops, addclass

If have a fairly complex function we are using to generate a custom loop of 3 most recent posts. I am simply trying to add a class to the last li element called "last" but not really getting it down. I tried a bunch of jquery to addClass but no luck. I am sure it is just me being dumb. Any help would be greatly appreciate. Here is my function:

```
    <?php function custom_readmore_after_excerpt($text) {  
        global $post;  
        //set default Read More 
            $link_text = '[continue]'; 
            $custom_fields = get_post_custom() ; 
            $thesis_content_fields = unserialize( $custom_fields['_thesis_post_content'][0] ); 
            if ( $thesis_content_fields['read_more'] )  
            $link_text = $thesis_content_fields['read_more']; 

            $link = '<span><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="feed_read_more">' . $link_text . '</a></span>';  

        if (!empty($post->post_excerpt)) {  
            $text = $text . $link;  
            } 
        else {  
            $text = str_replace('[...]', $link, $text);  
            }    
        return $text;   
        } 
        add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_readmore_after_excerpt');


            function excerpt_front($length) {
            return 16;
            }

            add_filter('excerpt_length', 'excerpt_front');

            $custom_loop = new WP_Query('showposts=3&orderby=date');
            $output = "";
                if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : 
                    /* open box wrapper */
                    $output .= "<ul class=\"feed_wrapper\">\n";
                while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post();
                    /* load post data */
                global $post;
                    /* prepare necessary variables */
                    $img = "";
                    $post_url = get_permalink($post->ID);
                    $post_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
                    $post_excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post->ID);
                    $a_title = esc_attr($post_title); /* - double Title on some post .. humm ?? - */
                    $thumbnail_data = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_thesis_post_thumbnail', true);
                    /* do only if thumbanil_data is not empty and is an array of values */
                if(!empty($thumbnail_data) && is_array($thumbnail_data)) {
                    $thumbnail_url = (!empty($thumbnail_data['image']['url'])) ? $thumbnail_data['image']['url'] : "";
                    $img = "<img src=\"{$thumbnail_url}\" class=\"feed_thumbnail\" alt=\"{$a_title}\" />";
                    }
                    $a_before = "<a href=\"{$post_url}\">";
                    $a_after = "</a>";
                    /* start html constructor */
                    /* open post wrapper */
                $output .= "<li>\n<div class=\"feed_container\">\n";
                /* headline */
                $output .= "<div class=\"feed_headline\">\n<h4 class=\"feed_title\">{$a_before}{$post_title}{$a_after}</h4>\n</div>\n";
                /* thumbnail */
                $output .= "<div class=\"feed_thumb\">\n{$a_before}{$img}{$a_after}\n</div>\n";
                /* thumbnail */
                $output .= "<div class=\"feed_excerpt\">\n{$post_excerpt}</div>\n";
                /* close and clear post wrapper */
                $output .= "<div class=\"clear\"></div>\n</div></li>\n";
                endwhile;
                /* close and clear box wrapper */
            $output .= "<div class=\"cleared\"></div>\n</ul>\n";
            endif;
            wp_reset_query();
            wp_reset_postdata();
            /* display result */
            echo $output; 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$(".feed_wrapper > li:last-child").addClass("last");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3hJEe/1/

After reading your comment below and visiting your website, this should work for your case:

```
$(".feed_wrapper > li").last().addClass("last");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3hJEe/2/

Comment: I have tried this in several permutations but for some reason it is not working when I add it to my site. It works great in the jfiddle but not on my WP site. http://www.everymountain.net/

Comment: updated my answer, also FYI, the reason the first way isn't working is because you have a `div` below your `li`'s within your `ul`

Comment: Thank you...this one worked! Curious why does the syntax change because of using a div inside my UL element. Are you referring to the <div class="clear"></div> piece?

Comment: Yes, the div was the last child. `li` wasn't the last child, but there was a `last()` of the group of `li`s

Comment: UL can only have LI as child elements, so with your DIV element in there you are creating invalid HTML.

Comment: Need a little more help if anyone is out there: trying to add a class of "last" to the last LI element in the recent articles sidebar widget. Can some one take a look at this page and suggest a jQuery statement that will work for this one: http://www.everymountain.net/about-becky-robinson/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".feed_wrapper li:last-child").addClass("last")
```

Something like this should do it.

Comment: I have tried this in several permutations but for some reason it is not working when I add it to my site. It works great in the jfiddle but not on my WP site. everymountain.net